# Online user outside of app android?

Tags: android, listview, dialog, push-notification

Hi I want to show online users out side of the app as a dialog window .I tried to list users in the listview with dialog .But it show full screen.But I want to show like as in below image.Please help me?[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use app widget for this purpose if you want to show application's data on home screen.
Check about what is app widget.

Comment: Ok.I will check and let you know.Thanks.

Comment: Can we add multiple app widgets one by one?.And Can we scroll app widget?

Comment: i guess app widget is totally a different scope here,and it would be better if you search about it more before asking question here.
App widget needs to be added by user because no app can access home screen.Yes you can implement ListView (scrollable and clickable entity) in app widget after some api level.Search for that.

Comment: ,I want to show online users outside of app using app widget .Is there any possiblities to display outside of app and over any other app?

Comment: Yes,you can do that but keep in mind that this requires you to do polling and that drains the battery a lot.You can communicate with app widget which resides on home screen and show network operation based result on it.But the operation is very costly.